# jzy3d builder cannot be resolved error on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jzy3d

So, I've recently downloaded (via Maven) jzy3d library so that I can translate and improve an existing program of mine from JS to Java, and to get a handle on the new library I was trying some examples available on the [library site](http://www.jzy3d.org/tutorial.php) but, as the title shows I keep getting the "Builder cannot be resolved" error.
I've tried to add the *org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Builder* import but also without success, as it returns a non used import alert.

This is my code:

```
package randomProjects;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.ChartLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Range;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.concrete.OrthonormalGrid;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;

public class SurfPlotTest_JZY3D {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        // Define a function to plot
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
            public double f(double x, double y) {
                return 10 * Math.sin(x / 10) * Math.cos(y / 20) * x;
            }
        };

        // Define range and precision for the function to plot
        Range range = new Range(-150, 150);
        int steps = 50;

        // Create a surface drawing that function;
        Shape surface = Builder.buildOrthonormal(new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
        surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface.getBounds().getZmin(), surface.getBounds().getZmax(), new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
        surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
        surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);
        surface.setWireframeColor(Color.BLACK);

        // Create a chart and add the surface
        Chart chart = new Chart(Quality.Advanced);
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
        ChartLauncher.openChart(chart);
        
    }
    
}
```

And this is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Builder cannot be resolved
    The field Quality.Advanced is not visible

    at randomProjects.SurfPlotTest_JZY3D.main(SurfPlotTest_JZY3D.java:30)
```

I also find important to mention that there is another error in the program at line #37, that I've tried fixing exchanging *Quality.Advanced* by *Quality.Advanced()*, but again, without any success what so ever.

A bit of an update in the hope of an answer

If I use the manually imported project files, also available in the library site, I don't get the builder error, but instead when compiling it returns the following error.

```
The project: org.jzy3d-0.9 which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

And this is the example code present in the project

```
package org.jzy3d.demos.surface;

import org.jzy3d.chart.Chart;
import org.jzy3d.chart.controllers.keyboard.camera.CameraKeyController;
import org.jzy3d.colors.Color;
import org.jzy3d.colors.ColorMapper;
import org.jzy3d.colors.colormaps.ColorMapRainbow;
import org.jzy3d.demos.AbstractDemo;
import org.jzy3d.demos.DemoLauncher;
import org.jzy3d.maths.Range;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Builder;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.Mapper;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.builder.concrete.OrthonormalGrid;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.primitives.Shape;
import org.jzy3d.plot3d.rendering.canvas.Quality;

public class ColorWaveDemo extends AbstractDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DemoLauncher.openDemo(new ColorWaveDemo());
    }

    public ColorWaveDemo() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Define a function to plot
        Mapper mapper = new Mapper() {
            public double f(double x, double y) {
                return x * Math.sin(x * y);
            }
        };

        // Define range and precision for the function to plot
        Range range = new Range(-3, 3);
        int steps = 80;

        // Create the object to represent the function over the given range.
        final Shape surface = Builder.buildOrthonormal(new OrthonormalGrid(range, steps, range, steps), mapper);
        surface.setColorMapper(new ColorMapper(new ColorMapRainbow(), surface.getBounds().getZmin(), surface.getBounds().getZmax(), new Color(1, 1, 1, .5f)));
        surface.setFaceDisplayed(true);
        surface.setWireframeDisplayed(false);

        // Create a chart
        chart = new Chart(Quality.Advanced, getCanvasType());
        chart.getScene().getGraph().add(surface);
        chart.addController(new CameraKeyController());
    }
}
```

Consider me a complete noob in importing libraries via Maven or otherwise, I'm doing all this to get a handle and learn how to, so I would appreciate a detailed answer. If needed I can also include my .pom file.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial page from the website is quite outdated. You may find easier to use the [tutorials that are embedded in the library](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos), e.g. [this surface example](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/surface/SurfaceDemoAWT.java).

The [readme of this module](https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/tree/master/jzy3d-tutorials) should help as well.

Comment: Sorry for the really long time to respond, the past few wees have been hell on earth to me and just now I got the time to check your answer, which lead me to fix the .pom file error that I was having, but unfortunately the Quality.Advanced error remains intact, even if I change the entire code, not changing a semi-colon, by the one provided by you.

Comment: You have to replace Quality.Advanced field by Quality.Advanced() method call. See this line https://github.com/jzy3d/jzy3d-api/blob/master/jzy3d-tutorials/src/main/java/org/jzy3d/demos/surface/SurfaceDemoAWT.java#L54

Comment: so... The thing is that I've copied your example on Git Hub, _ipsis litteris_ and it still gives me the
`Builder cannot be resolved  
The field Quality.Advanced is not visible`
error, this time in the line 35 in the comment `// Define a function to plot`, can you still help me?

Comment: As there is no reference to Quality.Advanced as a field in the demo, but only to Quality.Advanced() as a method, I presume something got wrong in your project dependencies. I suggest you restart a new project based on the example I provided.